# Perl read mathtype equation

Tags: perl

I read a word document containing Mathtype equation using Perl and then print it to txt file. It replace every euation with "SOH" charactor. How can I convert only equations from MathType to tex or latex like:

```
$y=\frac{2-x}{x-1} $
```

Here's my code:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::OLE 'CP_UTF8';
$Win32::OLE::CP = CP_UTF8;
binmode STDOUT, 'encoding(CP932)';

my $document_name = 'C:\\Strawberry\\tam_dev\\input\\deso7.doc';
open (my $fh1, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'C:\\Strawberry\\tam_dev\\output\\deso7.txt');
my $word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application','Quit') or die Win32::OLE->LastError();
$word->{visible} = 1;
my $document = $word->Documents->Open($document_name) or die Win32::OLE->LastError();
my $paragraphs = $document->Paragraphs ();
my $n_paragraphs = $paragraphs->Count ();
for my $p (1..$n_paragraphs) {
    my $paragraph = $paragraphs->Item ($p);
    print $fh1 $paragraph->Range->Text ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One place to start would seem to be the MathType SDK: http://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/default.htm